# How to use jQuery function on onKeyPress input event? (Magento 2)

Tags: magento2, validation, zipcode, input

I have this field (postcode or zipcode)

```
<input class="input-text col s12 zipcode" type="text" data-bind="
value: value,
valueUpdate: 'keyup',
hasFocus: focused,
attr: {
    name: inputName,
    placeholder: placeholder,
    'aria-describedby': getDescriptionId(),
    'aria-required': required,
    'aria-invalid': error() ? true : 'false',
    id: uid,
    disabled: disabled
}" name="postcode" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" id="zipcode" onKeyPress="MascaraCep(co-shipping-form.zipcode)">
```

CEP

wich has `onKeyPress="MascaraCep(co-shipping-form.zipcode)` event

and my masks.js:

/**
    Application
    */

```
require(['jquery'], function($) {

    console.log("Masks is loaded (mage2/m2materialize/web/js/masks.js)");

    /* Start */

    $(document).ready(function(){

        /* Start */


        //adiciona mascara de cep
        function MascaraCep(cep){
                        if(mascaraInteiro(cep)==false){
                        event.returnValue = false;
                }       
                return formataCampo(cep, '00.000-000', event);
        }

        //valida numero inteiro com mascara
        function mascaraInteiro(){
                if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57){
                        event.returnValue = false;
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
        }

        //formata de forma generica os campos
        function formataCampo(campo, Mascara, evento) { 
                var boleanoMascara; 

                var Digitato = evento.keyCode;
                exp = /\:|\-|\.|\/|\(|\)| /g
                campoSoNumeros = campo.value.toString().replace( exp, "" ); 

                var posicaoCampo = 0;    
                var NovoValorCampo="";
                var TamanhoMascara = campoSoNumeros.length;; 

                if (Digitato != 8) { // backspace 
                        for(i=0; i<= TamanhoMascara; i++) { 
                                boleanoMascara  = ((Mascara.charAt(i) == ":") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == "-") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == ".") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == "/")) 
                                boleanoMascara  = boleanoMascara || ((Mascara.charAt(i) == "(") 
                                                                        || (Mascara.charAt(i) == ")") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == " ")) 
                                if (boleanoMascara) { 
                                        NovoValorCampo += Mascara.charAt(i); 
                                          TamanhoMascara++;
                                }else { 
                                        NovoValorCampo += campoSoNumeros.charAt(posicaoCampo); 
                                        posicaoCampo++; 
                                  }              
                          }      
                        campo.value = NovoValorCampo;
                          return true; 
                }else { 
                        return true; 
                }
        }


    });

});
```

but my console display:

```
Masks is loaded (mage2/m2materialize/web/js/masks.js)
Uncaught ReferenceError: MascaraCep is not defined
```

Comment: I found a solution, for checkout inputs I am using:
https://packagist.org/packages/piszczek/magento2-inputmask

And for customer shipping address I can use jquery to add mask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, for checkout inputs I am using: packagist.org/packages/piszczek/magento2-inputmask And for customer shipping address I can use jquery to add mask

```
checkout_index_index.xml

<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
<!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
<item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract</item>
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
    <label translate="true">Zip Code</label>
    <placeholder>00.000-000</placeholder>
</item>
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="validate-zip-br" xsi:type="string">true</item>
</item>
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <!-- Assigning a new template -->
    <item name="inputMask" xsi:type="array">
        <!-- pass your simple mask here-->
        <item name="mask" xsi:type="string">00.000-000</item>
    </item>
    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/form/element/zipcode</item>
</item>
<item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">65</item>
```

adde    Magento_Customer/templates/address/edit.phtml:

```
<script>
require([
    "jquery",
    "mage/mage"
], function($){

    $('#zip').keypress(function(event){
        var input = $('#zip');
        MascaraCep(input, event);
    });

    $('#zip').on('blur', function(event){
        var input = $('#zip');
        completeAdress(input, event);
    });

    var completeAdress = function(code) {

            //Nova variável "cep" somente com dÃ­gitos.
            var cep = $("#zip").val().replace(/\D/g, '');

            //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
            if (cep != "") {

                //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
                var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

                //Valida o formato do CEP.
                if(validacep.test(cep)) {

                    //Consulta o webservice viacep.com.br/
                    $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/"+ cep +"/json/?callback=?", function(dados) {

                        if (!("erro" in dados)) {
                            //Atualiza os campos com os valores da consulta.
                            $("#street_1").val(dados.logradouro);

                            $("#street_4").val(dados.bairro);

                            $("#city").val(dados.localidade);

                            $("#street_3").val(dados.complemento);

                            var uf = dados.uf;

                            switch(uf) {
                                case "AC":
                                    uf = "Acre";
                                    break;
                                case "AL":
                                    uf = "Alagoas";
                                    break;
                                case "AP":
                                    uf = "Amapá";
                                    break;
                                case "AM":
                                    uf = "Amazonas";
                                    break;
                                case "BA":
                                    uf = "Bahia";
                                    break;
                                case "CE":
                                    uf = "Ceará";
                                    break;
                                case "ES":
                                    uf = "Espírito Santo";
                                    break;
                                case "GO":
                                    uf = "Goiás";
                                    break;
                                case "MA":
                                    uf = "Maranhão";
                                    break;
                                case "MG":
                                    uf = "Mato Grosso";
                                    break;
                                case "MS":
                                    uf = "Mato Grosso do Sul";
                                    break;
                                case "MT":
                                    uf = "Minas Gerais";
                                    break;
                                case "PA":
                                    uf = "Pará";
                                    break;
                                case "PB":
                                    uf = "Paraíba";
                                    break;
                                case "PR":
                                    uf = "Paraná";
                                    break;
                                case "PE":
                                    uf = "Pernambuco";
                                    break;
                                case "PI":
                                    uf = "Piauí";
                                    break;
                                case "RJ":
                                    uf = "Rio de Janeiro";
                                    break;
                                case "RN":
                                    uf = "Rio Grande do Norte";
                                    break;
                                case "RS":
                                    uf = "Rio Grande do Sul";
                                    break;
                                case "RO":
                                    uf = "Rondônia";
                                    break;
                                case "RR":
                                    uf = "Roraima";
                                    break;
                                case "SC":
                                    uf = "Santa Catarina";
                                    break;
                                case "SP":
                                    uf = "São Paulo";
                                    break;
                                case "SE":
                                    uf = "Sergipe";
                                    break;
                                case "TO":
                                    uf = "Tocantins";
                                    break;
                                case "DF":
                                    uf = "Distrito";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    uf = false;
                            }

                            if(uf){
                                $("#region_id > option:contains("+uf+")").attr("selected","selected");
                            }

                        } //end if.
                        else {
                            //CEP pesquisado não foi encontrado.
                            // limpa_formulário_cep();
                            alert("CEP não encontrado.");
                        }
                    });
                } //end if.
                else {
                    //cep Ã© inválido.
                    // limpa_formulário_cep();
                    alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
                }
            } //end if.
            else {
                //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
                // limpa_formulário_cep();
            }

        }

    function MascaraCNPJ(cnpj){
            if(mascaraInteiro(cnpj)==false){
                    event.returnValue = false;
            }       
            return formataCampo(cnpj, '00.000.000/0000-00', event);
    }

    //adiciona mascara de cep
    function MascaraCep(cep, event){
        return formataCampo(cep, '00.000-000', event);
    }

    //adiciona mascara ao telefone
    function MascaraTelefone(tel){  
            if(mascaraInteiro(tel)==false){
                    event.returnValue = false;
            }       
            return formataCampo(tel, '(00) 0000-0000', event);
    }

    //adiciona mascara ao telefone
    function MascaraCelular(tel){  
            if(mascaraInteiro(tel)==false){
                    event.returnValue = false;
            }       
            return formataCampo(tel, '(00) 00000-0000', event);
    }

    //adiciona mascara ao CPF
    function MascaraCPF(cpf){
            if(mascaraInteiro(cpf)==false){
                    event.returnValue = false;
            }       
            return formataCampo(cpf, '000.000.000-00', event);
    }

    //valida telefone
    function ValidaTelefone(tel){
            exp = /\(\d{2}\)\ \d{5}\-\d{4}/
            if(!exp.test(tel.value))
                    alert('Numero de Telefone Invalido!');
    }

    //valida CEP
    function ValidaCep(cep){
            exp = /\d{2}\.\d{3}\-\d{3}/
            if(!exp.test(cep.value))
                    alert('Numero de Cep Invalido!');               
    }

    //valida data
    function ValidaData(data){
            exp = /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/
            if(!exp.test(data.value))
                    alert('Data Invalida!');                        
    }

    //valida o CPF digitado
    function ValidarCPF(Objcpf){
            var cpf = Objcpf.value;
            exp = /\.|\-/g
            cpf = cpf.toString().replace( exp, "" ); 
            var digitoDigitado = eval(cpf.charAt(9)+cpf.charAt(10));
            var soma1=0, soma2=0;
            var vlr =11;

            for(i=0;i<9;i++){
                    soma1+=eval(cpf.charAt(i)*(vlr-1));
                    soma2+=eval(cpf.charAt(i)*vlr);
                    vlr--;
            }       
            soma1 = (((soma1*10)%11)==10 ? 0:((soma1*10)%11));
            soma2=(((soma2+(2*soma1))*10)%11);

            var digitoGerado=(soma1*10)+soma2;
            if(digitoGerado!=digitoDigitado)        
                    alert('CPF Invalido!');         
    }

    //valida numero inteiro com mascara
    function mascaraInteiro(event){
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57){
                    event.returnValue = false;
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
    }

    //valida o CNPJ digitado
    function ValidarCNPJ(ObjCnpj){
            var cnpj = ObjCnpj.value;
            var valida = new Array(6,5,4,3,2,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2);
            var dig1= new Number;
            var dig2= new Number;

            exp = /\.|\-|\//g
            cnpj = cnpj.toString().replace( exp, "" ); 
            var digito = new Number(eval(cnpj.charAt(12)+cnpj.charAt(13)));

            for(i = 0; i<valida.length; i++){
                    dig1 += (i>0? (cnpj.charAt(i-1)*valida[i]):0);  
                    dig2 += cnpj.charAt(i)*valida[i];       
            }
            dig1 = (((dig1%11)<2)? 0:(11-(dig1%11)));
            dig2 = (((dig2%11)<2)? 0:(11-(dig2%11)));

            if(((dig1*10)+dig2) != digito)  
                    alert('CNPJ Invalido!');

    }

    //formata de forma generica os campos
    function formataCampo(campo, Mascara, evento) { 
            var boleanoMascara; 

            var Digitato = evento.keyCode;
            exp = /\:|\-|\.|\/|\(|\)| /g
            campoSoNumeros = campo.val().toString().replace( exp, "" ); 

            var posicaoCampo = 0;    
            var NovoValorCampo="";
            var TamanhoMascara = campoSoNumeros.length;; 

            if (Digitato != 8) { // backspace 
                    for(i=0; i<= TamanhoMascara; i++) { 
                            boleanoMascara  = ((Mascara.charAt(i) == ":") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == "-") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == ".") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == "/")) 
                            boleanoMascara  = boleanoMascara || ((Mascara.charAt(i) == "(") 
                                                                    || (Mascara.charAt(i) == ")") || (Mascara.charAt(i) == " ")) 
                            if (boleanoMascara) { 
                                    NovoValorCampo += Mascara.charAt(i); 
                                      TamanhoMascara++;
                            }else { 
                                    NovoValorCampo += campoSoNumeros.charAt(posicaoCampo); 
                                    posicaoCampo++; 
                              }              
                      }      
                    campo.val(NovoValorCampo);
                      return true; 
            }else { 
                    return true; 
            }
    }

});
```

thanks